# Idiomatic way to detect sequences of x times same object in an Array in Smalltalk?

Tags: arrays, smalltalk, pharo, idioms

What's the idiomatic way to detect sequences of x times the same object (or an object with a specific matching parameter) in an OrderedCollection or Array?

E.g. does the Array contain 10 times the number 5 in a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the sequences of repeating objects is as simple as:

```
({ 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 5. 5. 3. 9. 9. 9. 9. } as: RunArray) runs 
=> #(2 3 2 1 4)
```

If you want to test if there is a run satisfying specific constraints, you can do something like the following:

```
meetsConstraint := false.
({ 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 5. 5. 3. 9. 9. 9. 9. } as: RunArray) runsAndValuesDo: [:run :value | 
    meetsConstraint := (value = 9 and: [run > 3])].
```

If you want to test for a certain property of an object instead of object equality, you can easily create a `RunArray` of this property by doing a `collect:` on it.

So the generalized solution would look something like this:

```
SequenceableCollection >> containsRunOf: anElement withAtLeast: nElements
    (self as: RunArray) runsAndValuesDo: [:run :value | 
        (value = anElement and: [run >= nElements]) ifTrue: [^ true]].
    ^ false
```

And then:

```
({ 'aa'. 'bb'. 'c'. 'ddd'. } collect: [:each | each size])
    containsRunOf: 2 withAtLeast: 3
=> false
```

Comment: Nice. I would propose the selector `#contains:runsOf:` as in `#(2 1 1 1 2) contains: 3 runsOf: 1`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I'm also not really happy with the name yet. However, `contains:runsOf:` also wouldn't be to the point, since one `run` really refers to the whole block of equal objects. So `runsOf:` would imply testing for multiple runs, while we actually test for one run of size `x`. Maybe something better will come to my mind...

Comment: Understood. Then I think I would stick to `contains: n consecutiveTimes: anObject`, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Why wasn't this the answer? RunArray is the obvious way to go. Personally, I would never add a #contains:consecutiveTimes: method to the system. Just because you can do some things, doesn't mean you should. My rule always was, after 3 different use cases have wanted the same service from a system object, then go ahead and dress it up with a generally reusable API.

Comment: @TravisGriggs You are right. I liked all the answers and upvoted all. The problem is, I can only accept one. Leo's one was the Smalltalkish one, I was looking for. As I use it a lot I assumed Leandro Caniglia's code would run faster. I changed the accepted answer..

Answer (score 4):

I like Uko's answer and would like to provide a different solution which addresses the "matching parameter" part of your question. In `SequenceableCollection`define:

```
contains: m consecutiveElementsSatisfying: block
    | n i |
    self isEmpty ifTrue: [^m = 0].
    n := self size - m + 1.
    i := 1.
    [i <= n] whileTrue: [| j |
        (block value: (self at: i)) ifTrue: [
            j := 2.
            [j <= m and: [block value: (self at: i + j - 1)]]
                whileTrue: [j := j + 1].
            j > m ifTrue: [^true]].
        i := i + 1].
    ^false
```

Now, for example the two following expressions would evaluate to true

```
#(2 1 1 1 2) contains: 3 consecutiveElementsSatisfying: [:e | e = 1]
#(2 1 0 1 2) contains: 3 consecutiveElementsSatisfying: [:e | e squared = e]
```

**Note**: If you want the `startingAt: n` version of this method just initialize `i := n` instead of `i := 1` just before the main loop.

*EDIT:*

And, of course, we can complete the protocol with the following method in `SequenceableCollection`:

```
contains: m consecutiveTimes: anObject
    ^self contains: m consecutiveElementsSatisfying: [:e | e = anObject]
```

And the example:

```
#(2 1 1 1 2) contains: 3 consecutiveTimes: 1
```

Comment: Cook, thank you. One question: why do you start counting `j` (actual detected number of items in a row) with 2 instead of with 1?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that you have to follow a pattern like this:

```
(collectionToTest
  indexOfSubCollection: (
    Array
      new:     numberOfRepetitions
      withAll: desiredObject)
    startingAt: 1
) isZero not
```

Maybe I don't know some of useful methods in Pharo, but if you define the ones like:

```
SequenceableCollection >> indexOfSubCollection: aSubCollection
  ^ aSubCollection indexOfSubCollection: aSubCollection startingAt: 0

SequenceableCollection >> containsSubCollection: aSubCollection
  ^ (aSubCollection indexOfSubCollection: aSubCollection) isZero not

Object >> asArrayOf: aLength
  ^ Array new: aLength withAll: self
```

then the definition can be flattened into:

```
collectionToTest containsSubCollection:
  (desiredObject asArrayOf: numberOfRepetitions)
```

or for your example:

```
anArray containsSubCollection: (5 asArrayOf: 10)
```

*P.S. I'm not sure about the method names. Maybe `inArrayOf:` can be better then `asArrayOf:` and so on.*