# What's the idiomatic way to generate a reordered array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, idioms

I can come up with all sorts of ways to achieve this but I am looking for the most elegant, idiomatic way to do this in Ojective-C:

I have an array of alphabetically sorted currency codes from `[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];`. Now I want to generate a new array with the five most used currencies at the beginning of the array, and the remaining currencies still in alphabetical order following.

So the task is: move some elements of an array to the beginning of a new array, followed by the remaining elements in the original order but without the elements moved to the front and without any gaps.

My current solution is:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableCurrencyList;
mutableCurrencyList = [[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes] mutableCopy];
[mutableCurrencyList removeObject:@"USD"];
[mutableCurrencyList removeObject:@"EUR"];
[mutableCurrencyList removeObject:@"JPY"];
[mutableCurrencyList removeObject:@"GBP"];
[mutableCurrencyList removeObject:@"CAD"];
[mutableCurrencyList insertObject:@"USD" atIndex:0];
[mutableCurrencyList insertObject:@"EUR" atIndex:1];
[mutableCurrencyList insertObject:@"JPY" atIndex:2];
[mutableCurrencyList insertObject:@"GBP" atIndex:3];
[mutableCurrencyList insertObject:@"CAD" atIndex:4];
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the thrust of your question, but I'd sort by criteria #1 (most used), remove the first 5 elements, then sort the rest by criteria #2 (alpha), then simply "stitch" the two back together. So, it breaks down to: 1. Sort 2. Take 3. Sort 4. Stitch. Are you asking for an algorithm like that, or the actual Obj-C code to obtain this?

Comment: @mbm29414 No, it's really a trivial question. I just realized, that i often do things more complicated than necessary because I am not familiar with common idioms of a language. [Especially with collection classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986199/idiomatic-way-to-detect-sequences-of-x-times-same-object-in-an-array-in-smalltal).

Comment: I think you make things more complicated because you use words like "idiomatic" rather than simply thinking about the sequence one would use to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how you determine which are the 5 most-used currencies. From your edit, it appears that you have a static list of these 5, so the following method is a way to do what you're asking:

```
- (NSArray *)orderedCurrencies {
    // You might determine this list in another way
    NSArray *fiveMostUsed           = @[@"USD", @"EUR", @"JPY", @"GBP", @"CAD"];
    // You already know about getting a mutable copy
    NSMutableArray *allCurrencies   = [[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes] mutableCopy];
    // This removes the 5 most-used currencies
    [allCurrencies removeObjectsInArray:fiveMostUsed];
    // This sorts the list of the remaining currencies
    [allCurrencies sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    // This puts the 5 most-used back in at the beginning
    [allCurrencies insertObjects:fiveMostUsed atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]];
    // This converts the mutable copy back into an immutable NSArray,
    // which you may or may not want to do
    return [allCurrencies copy];
}
```